# Split Fields in Access 2016

Tags: ms-access, split

Good Morning,

I have been tasked with trying to pull some information out of an Access database and am running into some issues.  I have two fields that have data combined within them and I need to extract part of the data out.  The first field prm1_benlimitcd displays as follows {P,S,"","","","","",""} and I need to extract the P out.  The second field prm1_benlimitamt displays as follows {55.22,16.92,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00} and I need to extract out the first number, in this case 55.22.  This is used to calculate available PTO and each employee is different.

Any help is much appreciated and I can provide any information necessary.

Thanks,
Brent

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want.

```
Option Compare Database

Public Function GetValueFromDelimString(sPackedValue As String, nPos As Long, Optional sDelim As String = ",")

Dim sElements() As String

sElements() = Split(sPackedValue, sDelim)
If UBound(sElements) < nPos Then
    GetValueFromDelimString = ""
Else
    GetValueFromDelimString = Replace(sElements(nPos), "{", "")
End If

End Function
```

[image]

[image]